# how to pass calender value to the datepicker?

Tags: android, datepicker

i have calender in one page and datepicker in another page. whenever i selected a date in calender selected date has to be set automatically in datepicker. Is it possible. Please help me

Comment: Show us some code, please.

Comment: i have got the code for setting the value in textbox